# I received a warning missing-exports-condition, How do I resolve this warning?

Tags: javascript, typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I received a warning missing-exports-condition, any body can help me how to resolve this issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d274k.png)

"@sveltejs/kit": "^2.3.2",
"typescript": "^5.3.3",

I've follow the below step but not resolved issue.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXCZU.png)

Comment: Are the packages mentioned by the warning yours? If not, it's not anything for you to worry about. Also, do not screenshot text, insert it as text and format it as code or quote.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557